# Query slowness with joins and like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-administration, sql-server-2017

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT B.TransactionId 
FROM BillingInfo B
INNER JOIN OfficeCustomers OC ON B.CustomerId = OC.Id
INNER JOIN CustomerContact CC ON CC.Id = OC.ContactId
WHERE CC.FirstName + ' ' + CC.LastName LIKE '%yog%'
ORDER BY B.TransactionId 
    OFFSET (0) ROWS FETCH NEXT (50) ROWS ONLY
```

[Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJfpz2Pzp)

This query takes around 6 seconds to complete. What can be done to improve the performance?

Comment: Do you really want to check whether the combination of first name and last name contains `yog`? This seems wrong to me. I guess that's not only slow, but even incorrect. Shouldn't this rather be `FirstName LIKE '%yog%' OR LastName LIKE '%yog%'`?

Comment: Don't use a leading `%` in your `LIKE` statement - that makes any use of indexes impossible and drastically slows down querying

Comment: The execution plan is driven by a scan in order of `TransactionId` and it estimates that it will only have to read 101.125 rows from that to find the first 50 matching the condition (reality 558,609) so it understimates the number of executions for all the stuff inside all the nested loops - what perf do you get with `DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL` hint?

Comment: Also your `where` criteria is not *sargable*, this alone is forcing SQL Server to scan every row

Comment: Please show your full tables and index definitions.

Comment: When leading % is not used in where clause the query works fast. I am thinking there is no way to improve the query performance when leading % is used ?

Comment: there are ways to get better performance but it requires some effort, such as using [trigram search](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search)

Comment: Did you try appending `OPTION (USE HINT ('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL'))` to the query as suggested?

Answer (score 0):

The two comments are accurate.

If possible, replace `LIKE '%yog%` by `LIKE 'yog%`.

You can also try the following query:

```
WITH contacts AS
(
    SELECT CC.Id
    FROM CustomerContact CC
    WHERE CC.FirstName LIKE '%yog%' OR CC.LastName LIKE '%yog%'
)
SELECT B.TransactionId 
FROM BillingInfo B
    INNER JOIN OfficeCustomers OC ON B.CustomerId = OC.Id
    INNER JOIN contacts CC ON CC.Id = OC.ContactId
ORDER BY B.TransactionId
OFFSET (0) ROWS FETCH NEXT (50) ROWS ONLY;
```

You can also create the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDE IX_BillingInfo_Customers ON BillingInfo
(
    CustomerId
)
INCLUDE
(
    TransactionId
)
```

Comment: The subquery isn't going to help unless you can force it to be calculated first, eg by moving the `OFFSET FETCH` inside it.